# What is the best way to extract the address pieces from this google places API address result?

Tags: javascript, json, google-places-api

This may be a simple JSON related question. I'm successfully receiving a JSON object from Google Places API that looks exactly like this example from the Google Places API docs. I need to assign each of the address components (street number, city, state, zip, etc...) to a separate variable in my code. How do I, for example, best reference the street_number ?

Here's how I'm doing it now and it will not work, because, for example, if my address does not have a 'floor', then I would have to reference `address_components[0]` instead of `address_components[1]` . Here's the way that I'm doing it now that will not work:

```
const MyStreetNumber =  details.address_components[1].long_name
console.log(MyStreetNumber) //logs 48
```

And here is the definition of 'details' (the response i'm receiving from Google Places API) :

```
  {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "5",
            "short_name" : "5",
            "types" : [ "floor" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Rd",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Council of the City of Sydney",
            "short_name" : "Sydney",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "New South Wales",
            "short_name" : "NSW",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Australia",
            "short_name" : "AU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "2009",
            "short_name" : "2009",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "5, \u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e48 Pirrama Rd\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003ePyrmont\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eNSW\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e2009\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eAustralia\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.866651,
            "lng" : 151.195827
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -33.8653881697085,
               "lng" : 151.1969739802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -33.86808613029149,
               "lng" : 151.1942760197085
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
      "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
      "name" : "Google",
      "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
      "rating" : 4.5,
      "reference" : "CmRSAAAAjiEr2_A4yI-DyqGcfsceTv-IBJXHB5-W3ckmGk9QAYk4USgeV8ihBcGBEK5Z1w4ajRZNVAfSbROiKbbuniq0c9rIq_xqkrf_3HpZzX-pFJuJY3cBtG68LSAHzWXB8UzwEhAx04rgN0_WieYLfVp4K0duGhTU58LFaqwcaex73Kcyy0ghYOQTkg",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "utc_offset" : 600,
      "vicinity" : "5, 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website" : "https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for-loop and check the `types` value, here's a simple example:

```
var add_comps = json['result']['address_components'];
for (var i = 0; i < add_comps.length; i++) {
  if (add_comps[i]['types'] == 'street_number') {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but if it's helpful for anybody it can be done like this:

> In case you only need the first result

```js
function handleGooglePlacesPress = results => {
  const map = {
    street_number: 'streetNumber',
    route: 'streetName',
    sublocality_level_1: 'city',
    locality: 'city1',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'state',
    postal_code: 'postalCode',
    country: 'country'
  };
  const brokenDownAddress = {};
  results[0].address_components.forEach(component => {
    brokenDownAddress[map[component.types[0]]] = component.long_name;
  }
  return brokenDownAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so I ended up just looping through details.address_components to assign the variables. I check city twice because sometimes it's called 'locality' and sometimes it's called 'subLocality_level_1' depending on country I believe:

```
function handleGooglePlacesPress(data,details){


 var StreetNumber = null;
 var StreetName = null;
 var City = null;
 var State = null;
 var Country = null;
 var PostalCode = null;

  const addressComponents = details.address_components;

  addressComponents.forEach(addressComponent => { 

      const addressType = addressComponent.types[0]

      if(addressType == 'street_number'){
        StreetNumber = addressComponent.long_name;
      }

      if(addressType == 'route'){
        StreetName = addressComponent.long_name;
      }

      if(addressType == 'sublocality_level_1'){
        City = addressComponent.long_name;
      }
      if(addressType == 'locality'){
        City = addressComponent.long_name;
      }

      if(addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1'){
        State = addressComponent.long_name
      }

      if(addressType == 'postal_code'){
        PostalCode = addressComponent.long_name
      }

      if(addressType == 'country'){
        Country = addressComponent.long_name
      }


  });


console.log(StreetNumber,StreetName,City,State,PostalCode,Country) //logs each address piece
```